# How to combine date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I am creating a Rails 3.2 app and I am not sure how to handle date and time.
Right now I have a field in the database called start_date which is a datetime timestamp and I also have a field called start_time.

I am using the fullcalendar plugin and for that to work I have to combine the start_date and start_time. How can I do this? (Not all events in the DB have a start_time).

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has the [`DateTime` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html), which essentially merges date and time together into one object. I would suggest making a migration that creates a new field that is called `start` and then combining your existing `start_date` and `start_time` fields into one:

```
def up
  add_column :events, :start, :datetime

  Event.find_each do |e|
    d = e.start_date
    t = e.start_time
    e.start = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec)
  end

  remove_column :events, :start_date
  remove_column :events, :start_time
end

def down
  add_column :events, :start_date, :datetime
  add_column :events, :start_time, :datetime

  Event.find_each do |e|
    s = e.start
    e.start_date = s.to_date
    e.start_time = s.to_time
  end

  remove_column :events, :start
end
```

If you need to get the date or time components in the future, you can use `to_date` or `to_time`, and the combined `DateTime` should work well with fullcalendar.